# Is there a way to convert MongoDB db commands to sql query format?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I understand that we can extract data from MongoDB using sql query via JDBC connectors such as Progress. But is there a way to convert the sql queries back to MongoDB command?

For example, we can accomplish MySQL to MongoDB using http://www.querymongo.com/, but is there any way to do the reverse?

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is not [on-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I'd suggest [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) as a more appropriate Stack Exchange site to try. Also note: the Query Mongo site generates crufty code for circa-2011 MongoDB and is definitely not relevant for modern versions of MongoDB (or best practice queries). The [`group()` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/) used in the Query Mongo example was deprecated in MongoDB 3.4 (Nov 2016).